# Odd Stored Procedure error - syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create a simple stored procedure in SQL Server 2005, and am puzzled by a syntax error I am getting.

Both tables have identical structure. `tbl_Users_non_61` is empty and ready to receive the data.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Make_WEEKLY_SUMMARY 
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   Select (tbl_Users.UserID
      , tbl_Users.RegistrationType
      , tbl_Users.Datecompleted)
   INTO tbl_Users_non_61  
   FROM 
   SELECT tbl_Users.UserID
      , tbl_Users.RegistrationType
      , tbl_Users.Datecompleted
   FROM tbl_Users;
END
GO
```

Resulting error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Make_WEEKLY_SUMMARY, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you just want to insert records into one table from another, there is a cleaner syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Users_non_61(UserId, RegistrationType, DateCompleted)
SELECT u.UserID, u.RegistrationType, u.Datecompleted
FROM tbl_Users AS u
```

To answer your question though, you do not need the `( )` around your first select, but you DO need them around your sub select, then you need to alias the sub-query you are referencing with the `FROM`:

```
Select t.UserID, t.RegistrationType, t.Datecompleted
INTO tbl_Users_non_61
FROM 
(
   SELECT u.UserID, u.RegistrationType, u.Datecompleted
   FROM tbl_Users AS u
) as t;
```

Comment: In this particular case, wouldn't you no longer need a sub-query since the data to select into the new table comes from the same table? And shouldn't the `un.UserID` be using the `t` alias instead? I'm just wondering, in case this is another approach that has the same performance.. Thanks!

Comment: Good catch on the alias @Nonym.  I left the sub select in my answer to mention to the OP the need to wrap in () and alias for their future queries.  I wouldn't use the `INTO` option at all, however, and would go with my first suggestion of the `INSERT INTO ()   SELECT` approach

Comment: @Glenn It is corrected now, the `INTO` should not have an alias.  I rearranged this answer a few times, had some extra aliases when I was done initially.  Should be corrected now.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer. appreciate both your answer and Nonym's.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on:

```
SELECT
    tbl_Users.UserID
  , tbl_Users.RegistrationType
  , tbl_Users.Datecompleted 
INTO tbl_Users_non_61  
FROM tbl_Users;
```

When you `SELECT ... INTO`, if the columns come from one table only, there's no need to `SELECT` those same columns again. Even if you had to take data from multiple columns, you still wouldn't need to reselect them, and perform a join instead.

Comment: Good Catch, Nonym. I am going to add a WHERE clause...I was just trying the full insert to see how that works. Sorry for confusing the main issue.